# How to run scripts loaded in callback in Devexpress CallbackPanel

Tags: callback, devexpress

On my page I use Devexpress CallbackPanel to dynamically load its content including javascript blocks. Since DX does not (by default) run these scripts on callback end I found a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Only thing you need is to specify id of script block starting with prefix "dxss_" and then the magic works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="dxss_AnyTextHere">
  //some script here
</script>
```

Comment: Is this still valid in DevExpress 14.2?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry, i don't work with DX components anymore.

Comment: Still works in 15.1, so presumably 14.2 as well.  Use dxss_ for script blocks and dxis_ for script tags that load external files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASPxCallback client side event specified by "ClientSideEvents-EndCallback" where you can specify a javascript function.  From this function, you can call whatever scripts you add during the callback.

Comment: You cannot use EndCallback client-side handler in all cases. As I load different content into CallbackPanel I need different scripts to run after the content is loaded. That's why I found workaroud to this case which is in my answer.

Comment: @petriq You can use ASPxCallbackPanel.JSProperties to set custom property which can be used in EndCallback event. So, you can execute different scripts based on custom property value. Your solution might work now (by the way, nice hack), but I'm almost sure that DevEx doesn't support it and could change this behaviour in future releases.